Logic app HTTP connector shows error : 'The SSL connection could not be established'
I can see an expectation while connecting to an on-premise-hosted API using the standard logic app from Azure. All required network connections are done and tested successfully. Local execution also works fine.
Same not working on Azure given below error
BadRequest
Http request failed as there is an error: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
screenshot attached:

I am looking forward to your suggestion to fix this.
Thanks,
Deepak SHAW.

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/621777/logic-apps-standard-http-request-failed-as-there-i @DeepakShaw
